# in filepond which event will use to handle uploaded files using react js

Tags: reactjs, filepond

Iam using filepond pond for uploading files to backend , uploading is working perfectly , but i want to block that current tab in the page until completion of uploads. for that i want to know that which event is handling for uploaded files. is there any event for checking is all files uploaded or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onprocessfiles` callback which is called when all files in the list have been processed.

More info: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#callbacks